# Dataweave Always output JSON number with two decimal places

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

I've got the following number coming through via xml in Dataweave.

```
<b:AmountValue>180.90</b:AmountValue>
```

Using Dataweave I am trying to output a corresponding json number with two decimal places (to represent currency).

Here is what my Dataweave expression looks like...

```
amount: $.AmountValue as :number as :string {format: ".00"} as :number
```

The output json is losing the trailing zero.

```
i.e. "amount":180.9
```

How can I change my Dataweave expression to always have two decimal places?

Or perhaps I'm misunderstanding the json number type?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remote the last `as :number` if you can live with amount being a string

```
amount: $.AmountValue as :number as :string {format: ".00"}
```

Comment: No. Sorry I cannot. It can't be a string

Comment: then you have to live with the missing zero. removing the trailing zero from the representation of a decimal is a accustomed behavior and the decision whether to do so or not is not made by the provider of the decimal (wich is you)

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you put just  `amount: $.AmountValue as :number`

I tried this on my preview of anypoint studio, and don't see losing the trailing 0. Also i am using the latest version.

Comment: if you convert a string to a number you no longer control the representation of the value. it might end up being displayed with trailing zero... or not

Answer (score 0):

I also tested this and it works.

If you try this:
`8.2 as :string {format: "0.00"} as :number`

then the extra decimal place is added.

If you output to application/json or application/XML you'll see the two decimal places printed out `8.20`. If you output to application/java, then it is a double, and you will have to decide how to print out the double.

If you try `8.2 as :number`, then it prints out as `8.2`.

Answer (score 0):

The coercion from from :string to :number, as previously stated, is what is dropping your trailing 0. Dataweave supports :number formatting dictated by use of an octothorp.

The below code snip will yield your required two decimal places.

```
 amount: $.AmountValue as  :number { format: "#.##"}
```

Comment: Hello zachcdr, please explain what your answer does so the author can understand how and why it works. For more information, see ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).