# Mule 3.9 Dataweave droping .00 from integer

Tags: json, mule, dataweave

Below is my sample code

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message" >
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[ %dw 1.0
                 %output application/json skipNullOn = "everywhere"
                 %function addTrailingZeros (numberWithoutTrailingZeros) (
                        numberWithoutTrailingZeros as :number  {class: "java.lang.BigDecimal"} 
                    )
                 ---
                 "test" : addTrailingZeros(12.00)
        ]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
```

Output i am getting is

```
{
"test": 12
}
```

But i want this
{
    "test": 12.00
}

I tried with {format:"#.00"} but it's not working. If you pass 12.01 its working.

Kindly help me on this issue.
Even simplest example

```
{"test" :  7.00 as :number {format:'#.###'}}
```

not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dataweave Always output JSON number with two decimal places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451524/dataweave-always-output-json-number-with-two-decimal-places)

Comment: Tried these approach before nothing working :(

Answer (score 2):

JSON numbers don't retain format. See this answer for a technical explanation of the limitations of numbers in JSON see https://stackoverflow.com/a/38357877/721855
If you need to retain a fixed number of decimal positions you could use a string instead. This is the same as printing a formatted decimal. Printing converts to a string the number.

Answer (score 0):

Check using this:

```
{
Book: payload.mybook as :string {format: ".00"}
}
```